# Newly entered field does not inserted in already created collection after updating mongoose schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have already created one MongoDB collection using mongoose schema from express web service after some days I found a requirement of a new field in mongoose table so added that field in mongoose schema and try to insert a value of newly added field along with existing fields but it's not get inserted in the newly added document.

So what I have done as a troubleshooting process, I deleted my existing collection totally and then inserted my new document in a collection, Then I found It started working properly. My newly inserted field get inserted into the collection. So Is there any other way to add a new field in MongoDB using mongoose without deleting the whole collection.

My existing user collection schema:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var userSchema = new Schema({
  username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  password: { type: String, required: true },
});

var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

When I inserted a new document with username and password In above collection It works fine.

My new user collection schema after adding new field (name):

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var userSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  password: { type: String, required: true },
});

var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

But After updating my user schema When I inserted a new document with name, username and password In above collection only insert username and password, name field does not get inserted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do one simple step, add default values to every field you create.
Example

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
  name: {type: String , default: ""},
  username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  password: { type: String, required: true },
});
```

Happy Coding

Answer (score 0):

Name should be also be an object in the schema like so

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
  name: {type: String},
  username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  password: { type: String, required: true },
});
```

Comment: It doesn't matter, How you define your field.